# SQL Query - How to query a recursive key

Tags: mysql, sql, recursion

I need to query a recursive key in one table

**The table:**

instructor_id

instructor_name

mentor_id

**problem**

mentor_id has the recursive foreign key

Some records have the same mentor_id.

How would I go about querying this table?

I need to output all the instructors who are mentoring others

Comment: @Sebas, what can be done in a stored procedure that can't be done outside of one?

Comment: @Tom, could you explain `Some fields have the same mentor_id.` please? Did you mean `Some records have the same mentor_id`?

Comment: Yes that's correct my bad. Some records have the same id. I have got my answer to this problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all instructors who are mentoring someone

```
SELECT instructor_id, instructor_name
FROM instructors
WHERE instructor_id IN (SELECT mentor_id FROM instructors)
```

EDIT: If you want all mentoring relationships

```
SELECT i.*, m.instructor_name AS mentor_name
FROM instructors i
  JOIN instructors m ON m.instructor_id = i.mentor_id
```

Comment: Would this be classed as a sub-query? Also I need to put those who are being instructed, within the same query, can that be done?

Comment: Yes. It is a subquery (but not a correlated subquery).

Comment: @Tom, there are possibly multiple people being mentored. Do you want one row for each instructor who is a mentor, or one row for each person being mentored?

Comment: One row for each person being mentored, then I could just order them by mentor id.

Comment: @Tom, okay, but that is a different question that what you originally asked: "I need to output all the instructors who are mentoring"

Comment: A list of instructors who are currently mentoring others, together with instructors in their teams. Is what I need to do. The question is quite confusing.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using a nested query is an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.* 
FROM yourTable t1 
INNER JOIN yourTable t2 ON t1.instructor_id = t2.mentor_id
```

Comment: "more efficient than a nested query" (A) Depends on the nested query (B) SQL is declarative. Query planners are free to do whatever they want to get the correct output. With a good planner, queries with the same results will have the same query plan.

Comment: Hi. I'm unsure about the t1 and t2 you have used. Could you explain?

Comment: `t1` and `t2` are table aliases. You don't need to change those.

Comment: @PaulDraper, yeah i suspected that could be the case. Will change that now. Yes, just change `yourTable` to `instructors` or whatever your table is called but I see you've taken the other answer anyway.

Comment: Although ironically, an `INNER JOIN` was needed for the solution to your actual problem

Comment: Maybe LEFT JOIN would fit better? In case an instructor does not have a mentor?

Comment: "One row for each person being mentored", suggests no rows for people who are not being mentored.